# Xamarin Splash Screen Android 11 VS Android 12

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to get a xamarin android app to show a splash screen. It worked fine on my Pixel 3a with android 11 but it does not work with android 12. I get the same problem with the Pixel 6 and S21 Ultra. I did find this on github but I have not found anything else on how to get around this issue

**Documented Issue**
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6517

**Repro to reproduce**
https://github.com/MicahArmantrout/SplashScreen

**styles.xml**

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light" />

</resources>
```

**SplashScreen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <item>
        <bitmap
          android:src="@drawable/splash"
          android:tileMode="disabled"
          android:gravity="center" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Android 11 Splash Screen

[image: Android 11]

Android 12 Splash Screen

[image: Android 12]

Run this code on a android 11 device then run it on a android 12 device

[image: Android 11 Splash]

When I try the suggestion in the github issue I get these runtime errors

Github
https://github.com/MicahArmantrout/SplashScreen/tree/main/ScreenTest%20WithBindingAlpha

Comment: How did you implement your splash screen?

Comment: in the android project with splashscreen.xml

Comment: Please see my updated question I added a example app @Rob

Comment: Instead of the splash.jpeg create a splash.xml. Then u also have more control about the properties of your picture.

Comment: use what kinda file @Rob

Comment: I have a splash.jpg that is called in splash_Screen.xml is that what your saying ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242079/discussion-between-micah-armantrout-and-rob).

Comment: Sorry, that's what u already did. Missed that.

Comment: you'll get more answers if you post the code in the question instead of links to it.

Comment: Code Added @JohnLord

Comment: Is Android 12 SDK installed?

Comment: it was not but it is now but no change in the splash screen

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my repro with a potential solution with two issues

- the screen looks zoomed in (maybe this can be fixed messing with image sizes)
- there is a colored screen right before the splash screen shows

https://github.com/MicahArmantrout/SplashScreen/tree/main/SplashScreen

if anyone gets this to fully work please let me know and I will update my solution

Comment: Hi - have you by any chance got a solution I have a xamarin forms solution and I need to support Android 12- 11 and 10 

Whatever I tried does not work to make the splash screen work 

many thanks

Comment: Sorry I realized that this not fully implemented in Xamarin and if I left it alone it would show the icon

Comment: Hi do you have a working solution? I am coming to a conclusion that with xamarin forms android 12 splash screen does not work . When you say "if I left alone it would show the icon" can you expand a bit what  you mean. Very grateful

Comment: Sure. Create a brand new project and run it. When it resumes and when its not side loaded(deployed from firebase) when it loads it show the icon of the app. I have not been successful with showing a image.