# Splash Screens for Android phones below Android 12

Tags: android, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I have a question regarding the new splash screen migration with Android 12.  I went through the migration, all phones that are not running Android 12 now have the default Droid as the splash screen popup.  I am curious how can I either have my legacy splash screen or replace the droid image for the phones that are not running Android 12.

Here is the GitHub for the Xamarin.Android Splash Screen Migration
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6517

Also here is the link to the Android Migration
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate

I can't find anything in the documentation about phones that are not running Android 12 and how to give the user something other than the Droid as a splash screen.

Comment: You can use the `SplashScreenCompat` library: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen

Comment: Im confused, I used the SplashScreen LIbrary which is what you link points too and the instructions told me in the link I posted above.  But any emulator  not using Android 12 I get just a default Android Splash screen.  I must be missing something.  This is also an Xamarin project and I am using Visual Studio not Android Studio

Comment: SplashScreen api support Android 12+ & SplashScreenCompat library api supports device below Android 12

Comment: Here is a [working workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71135199/xamarin-splash-screen-android-11-vs-android-12) but with some small issues , have you checked that ?

Comment: I am using SplashScreenCompat, for anyone whom may have question as long as you include this tag in the style and you size the Icon appropriately, you should be backwards compatible. Only use the icon name....dont use the file extension such as 'png' or 'jpeg'.  The way the documentation reads, that the legacy splash would still work after migration but it will not.  
<item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/IconName</item>

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT    The splash screen is working on Android 12.  However on Android 11 and lower, if the phone is in Light Mode the app loads with a white screen if its in Dark Mode then it will load in a Dark Mode.  Where in Android 12, I have defined the screen to be black, its always black, even when the phone is in light mode.  I am not sure what I have done wrong. Also my Branding image at the bottom of the splash screen is missing on Android 11 and lower.  I have googled an googled but I can't find what I have done wrong

Comment: You can check the answer I had edited in your last question. In addition, I had test this with kotlin in android studio, it worked well. So if the steps are correct but the result isn't correct, the cause may be the xamarin's compatibility.